# Common function to disable links double clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, primefaces

In my application I need to disable double click href links. There are many jsf pages which used primeface links  . So change everywhere is not a feasible solution.
Could anyone suggest that, is there any common function which we can achieve this functionality.

I tried override window.onbeforeunload function. But couldn't surpass that confirmation window and I couldn't achieve my desired objective from it.

Could I write any common javascript or jquery function to do this?

Comment: The most obvious way to do this would be to add a double click handler to the document with a selector for all your link classes that uses preventdefault, but since you don't show any code at all, it's difficult to be sure.

Comment: Can you try this?<p:commandButton value="Click Me" id="a08" partialSubmit="true"
 onclick="this.disabled=true;jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-disabled')"
actionListener="..."/>

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to disable all `<a>` tag `double click` then you might use this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("a","dblclick",function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             return false;
     });
});
```

Or if you wish to disable all `<a>` tag `double click` and also `click` then you might use this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("a","dblclick click",function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Use jQuery delegate event instead of live event. '$(document).on("a", "dblclick", function(e){e.preventDefault();})'. It works for all later created anchor in other places!

Answer (score -1):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    links[i].bind('dblclick',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   });

}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: oops, I meant document.getElementsByTagName("a")